# HTC Desire C screen on while charging

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, charging, screen

My new HTC Desire C screen does not turn off while charging. It is running ICS (Android version 4.0.3, HTC Sense version 4.0). I have went into Settings > Developer Tools > Stay Awake (OFF). It doesn't work. Screen timeout is set to 30 seconds.

I also downloaded and installed Extended Controls, but when I try to add the widget to the homescreen it tells me "Please reconnect your SD card first" (which is non-existent at the moment).

p.s. I downgraded from a Xperia Arc S in hopes of a simpler phone, and my god this Desire C is BAD.

Comment: I remember also having this problem with the HTC Diamond when I use a 3rd party charger. Do you still use the original charger?

Comment: Yup, I'm using the original charger

Answer (score 0):

I also see this behaviour with my Desire C model.  When I reported it as a bug to HTC they responded that it is intentional behaviour as the Desire C lacks a charging LED.  Personally I think you should still be able to have the screen turn off and it doesn't make sense to have an option in the settings menu that doesn't do anything.

If enough people request the change HTC may put in the ability to turn off the screen while charging in a future software update.